# Access Tables read/write with Java

Tags: java, mysql

I explained my question in the form of example, because I couldnt fit everything in it.

I have 3 tables in a local MS access database and I use SQL queries from java to read/write,

```
Table1 // 3 columns. 1) id 2) department1 yes/no 3) department2 yes/no
Table2 //Department1 with emails address //1 column. email address
Table3 //Department2 with emails address // 1 column. email address
```

The Features I know how to develop - From Interface, user enters an id and select Department 1 and/or Department 2. where the selections are saved in table1. Later on the emails will be sent from the software according to the data avaliable from table1. which i could able to do this task?

My question is, instead of sending emails to all email address in each department, I would like to provide an option to the user as

```
Department1//Jbutton
```

when user clicks the button, a popup should come up with all the email address avaliable  in that table and user should be able to select specify email address(more than one) and it should be saved in "SOME WAY" in another table or ....

```
SOME WAY - I am looking for a way to do this. 
Because each Id will not be sent to all email address in a department.
There will be lot of Id created everyday
I need to save them because, It works with a reminder system.
```

I am happy to provide some more information if needed, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need an sql query in your code that brings back all of the emails for the department wanted when a button is pressed? If so, your code and query will look something like

```
    if (buttonDepartment1.click){ //where the button pressed is called buttonDepartment1
        messageBoxDialog =('select * from Table1 where Department1 like "yes"')};
```

this is written from the top of my head, I'm not sure how perfect it is.

you will also need to write code to say when email chosen or clicked from list, to create table and insert that data into that table?

I'm not sure about the choosing email, but inserting into a new table won't be too hard, something like

```
    For (email){
       connection.query("create table email(select email from Table1 where id like"' + email + '")};
```

email being the one chosen from the table. You'll need to create the variable and store it in your code for use when it's chosen from the messageBox.

I'm sure there might be an easier way to do this, but as I said off the top of my head I think it's something like that you're looking for.

Comment: thanks mart87, I have lot of ideas in my mind and looking for a way to do that. I will work on it and post the updated code, if i finish it.